# Machine continues to freeze

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-12.04, freeze

As of lately, my desktop has been freezing at seemingly random times under no extraneous workloads.  I believe the issue is being caused by Firefox, but I am unsure and need help debugging the situation.

The machine currently has 2 hard drives; a SSD which is partitioned to dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04, and a standard hard drive which is partitioned to hold basic Windows documents (Documents, Desktop, Downloads, etc.) and /home and /usr/local for Ubuntu.  All applications (at least for Windows) are installed on the SSD.

The freezing is only an issue on Windows 7.  It also seems to occur randomly when browsing the web using Firefox.  I am unsure if this is due to the filesystem setup I have for my desktop or a possibly corrupted installation of Firefox (or other?).  I have never had the issue before (on any machine).  It should also be noted that I never experienced the issue on the machine before repartitioning the SSD to dual-boot.  If there is any information I can provide to help debug the situation, please let me know.

Comment: If it only happens under windows, try running "whocrashed." If FF also crashes under Linux, and as it happens only after dual-booting your system, maybe it's a grub2 (?? - or what do you use?) issue, in which case I'd post this on a ubuntu page or maybe superuser. You should add how you dual boot.

Comment: @gnometorule sorry for the late reply.  What is this "whocrashed" program?  I've never heard of it.  Further what do you mean how I dual boot?  I use the standard grub that comes with installing Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: (1) whocrashed: just google it. Crashes are often drivers or similar; if that's the case, whocrashed (freeware) can help you identify. (2) if it's grub (which didn't come with 12.04 when I installed it), above sites or "ubuntuforum" more likely to help. Gl! :)

Comment: PS: (a) as mentioned before, whocrashed only helps with windows crashes (for all I know). (b) ubuntuforum, in my experience, very friendly - post under "absolute beginners" probably (for the type of question, not so much your expertise. :))

Answer (score 0):

I also have had this problems in Windows 7. I used to use FireFox all the time but lately it seems like FireFox is causing more and more memory issues. Browsing in Chrome never gives problems. I also had these problems when watching video`s in FireFox. What I did do recently (only usefeull if you system is 64 bit) is install WaterFox. This is Firefox, but a build for 64 bit systems (non official build).

FireFox memory issues are solved ever since.

Also, because I regularely had a whole PC crash (my screen would suddenly show a brigh color of pink or blue and then totally stop working), I have installed AVG PC Tune Up. Since then, I haven`t had any crash anymore. See my reply on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791468/windows-7-frequent-computer-crashes-blue-screen/28807578#28807578